# Kotlin pass KType as generic parameter

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have a situation where I want to call a function to produce an object of a type for which I have just a KType description of.

Basically I have:

```
inline fun<reified T> coolFunction(from : String) : T = // Okay, I'll be honest - its a JSON parser
...
fun myOtherFunction(foo : KCallable<MyReturnType>) : MyReturnType {
    val args = mutableMapOf<KParameter, Any?>()
    ...
    for (parameter in foo.parameters) {
        ...
        val argValue = coolFunction<parameter.type>(someStringIhave)
        args[parameter.name] = argValue
    }
    ...
    return foo.callBy(args)
}
```

The issue is of course that the `coolFunction<parameter.type>(someStringIhave)` isn't correct syntax. I don't know how to get the right syntax though, I assume I'll have to use some more reflective API, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: The problem has more to do with the first function. How can it possibly return a T when there is no parameter for the class type, unless you use a reified type?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, it is reified. I still don't know how to call it correctly. I specifically am using the `Json.decodeFromString` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change your `coolFunction` to get the parameter. it can't be done with a generic function. unfortunately, you didn't provide the code for your `coolFunction` and I can't help you with its implementation but if you want to do this you should pass the class instead of using generics. and if you call other generic functions in your cool function change them all. pass the parameter and deal with it in your cool function. you can't call it this way there is no way. you have to change the signature.

also, your `args` was wrong. the keys should be parameters, not their name. I corrected it.

```
fun coolFunction(from: String, param: KParameter) {} // Okay, I'll be honest - its a JSON parser

fun myOtherFunction(foo : KCallable<String>) : MyReturnType {
    val args = mutableMapOf<KParameter, Any?>()

    for (parameter in foo.parameters) {
        val argValue = coolFunction("someStringIhave", parameter)
        args[parameter] = argValue
    }

    return foo.callBy(args)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The `coolFunction` was the kotlinx serialization JSON parser. I switched to Gson which has a function with a more appropriate signature. I was trying to avoid an additional dependency, but it looks like this is a shortcoming of the kotlinx json deserializer at the moment.

Comment: glad I could help